# How can I modify client SSH settings?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I am logged in a system as `student`. 
How can I modify client SSH settings so that when I write the following command `ssh 123.4.5.67` , SSH client authentificates me as another user?

Comment: `ssh 123.4.5.67 -l username`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well presented already in OpenSSH documentation such as man pages.

In the configuration file `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host 123.4.5.67
    User another
```

On the command line:

```
ssh -l another 123.4.5.67
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have a little problem... my ~/.ssh/config file does not exist

Comment: @pkenobi23 It's in your $HOME: create it yourself...